# Windows Phone 8 Templates disappeared

Tags: templates, windows-phone, visual-studio-2013

After installing the language pack of Visual Studio, to switch from italian to english language, windows phone templates disappeared. How can I restore them again? I have already tried to prompt the following command in a prompt with Administrator privilegies:
devenv /setup
devenv /InstallVSTemplates
devenv /ResetSettings

No way, it does not work yet. The version of Visual Studio is 2013 Ultimate.

Comment: Does the directory `...path-to-vs2013\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Windows Phone` still exist? The project templates should be there.

Comment: Well, the actual situation is the following.
I reinstalled the Windows Phone SDK, by using the MODIFY option of the uninstaller. There, it is possible to install only the sdk. 
So I got back the Windows Phone Templates, but only if I use the italian language in Visual Studio. Going in the directory that you said I saw that in the directory 1033 (the english one) there is no template, instead in 1040 (the italian one) there are.
What should I do now? If I copy the templates in the other directory, is it sufficient?

Comment: The easiest workaround would be to copy all things from the 1040 directory to `C:\Users\<yourusername>\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual C#`. However, a clean reinstall of VS would be the best. In general I wonder why you installed some WP SDK since VS2013 comes with it integrated by default.

Comment: Because templates disappeared as soon as I installed the english language pack.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue or so I thought.  It seems he templates are listed under Store Apps then Windows Phone Apps.  All my templates are in the 1033 folder as well in the visual studio install directory.

[image]